# Как получить не системное время и дату в python?

Tags: python, дата, datetime, время

Я хочу получить реальное мировое время и дату (Не важно по какому часовому поясу).

Я пытался выполнить вроде этого:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

И да, я получаю время и дату:

```
2021-06-30 12:14:46.893459
```

Но проблема в том, что если пользователь у себя изменит настройки даты и времени, то измениться и вывод который я получу, мне это не годиться.
Как я могу получить то же время и дату, вне зависимости от настроек пользователя?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/world-time-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Держи

```python
from WorldTimeAPI.schemas import *
from WorldTimeAPI.service import Client

payload = {"area":"EST"}

myclient = Client('timezone')

r = myclient.get(**payload)

if isinstance(r,ErrorJson):
    print(r.errMsg)
        
elif isinstance(r,DateTimeJson):
    print(r.datetime)
```

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow

`now()` выдает Вам Ваше текущее время, тогда как `utcnow()` общемировое, которое потом можно в локальные зоны перевести.

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())  # 2021-06-30 09:36:24.605686
print(datetime.datetime.now())  # 2021-06-30 12:36:24.605686
```

Если же нужно время от сервера, то тут лучше смотреть в сторону запроса к NTP серверам. К примеру через библиотеку ntplib https://github.com/Tipoca/ntplib

```
import ntplib
import datetime

conn = ntplib.NTPClient()
response = conn.request('0.ru.pool.ntp.org', version=3)
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(response.tx_time, datetime.timezone.utc))
```

Comment: Эти значения все-равно из системного времени берутся, а автору нужно время из сети

Comment: utcnow тоже из системного берется, просто без часового пояса

Comment: `ntplib` похоже сломана, по крайней мере в `Google Colab` ошибку даёт на любое имя сервера (

Comment: Только что проверял. Работает

Comment: @AndyPavlov В колабе выдаёт `gaierror: [Errno -8] Servname not supported for ai_socktype`. Если где-то ещё работает, то хорошо, конечно.

Comment: У себя на машине запустил из под Python 3.7 >> `2021-06-30 10:00:24.047060+00:00`

Comment: Запустил на Колабе. Да, там есть проблема. При этом у себя в чистой `venv` под Ubuntu все работает. Вопрос к питону у гугла. Там, кстати, в комментах к getaddrinfo написано у Гугла: `We override this function since we want to translate the numeric family and socket type values to enum constants.`